# UICollectionView with Decoration

Tags: uicollectionview

i need to change the UICollectionView Decoration like this image

http://cs3-3.4pda.to/2433011.jpg

need tutorial please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it in this tutorial

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel

thanks